# Read data from local folder in FLASK

Tags: javascript, api, flask, get

I am building a web API with FLASK and I want to read some images in `data` folder

```
venv/data/cartes/carte1.png
                 carte2.png
                 carte3.png
                 carte4.png
```

in order to show them in an html file `index.html` and loop over them whit javascript:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I tried to use this but it gaves error GET LINK... not found:

```
app.config["CLIENT_IMAGES"] = "/data/cartes"

@app.route("/get-image/<image_name>",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_image(image_name):

    try:
        return send_from_directory(app.config["CLIENT_IMAGES"], filename=image_name, as_attachment=True)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("failure")
        abort(404)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs:
(https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory)

```
@app.route('/get-image/<path:image_name>')
def get_image(image_name):
    return send_from_directory('/data/cartes', image_name, as_attachment=True)
```

You can find more examples here:
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/65747/flask.send_from_directory

Comment: I added this to my flask code, but how can I access to a specific image in "data/cartes/folder" in html file or with  JS.

Comment: `<img src="{{ url_for('get_image', filename=image_name) }}">`
Here's a fully detailed tutorial:  [link](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/handling-file-uploads-with-flask)  
Hope I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the static directory for that:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/static/

With `url_for` you can generate the relative path to any file in that directory.

The static directory exists, so that there is a clear distinction between public files and server side code files.

If you want to include images in a html file you can use them inside a template as

```html
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='smthn.png')}}"></img>
```

Comment: I am not sure if is it okay to store some image data in the static folder? (it's not logo or background image it's image uploaded by the user ..)